# Symfony 3 - Some difficulties to use templating service to send mail

Tags: php, symfony, email, service, templating

I have a Mail.php file that contains a sendMail function that will be used by several of my controllers.

I got to have to use the "templating" service. But I have problems putting it in place.

**My Services.yml:**

```
email_management:
    class: Site\PagesBundle\Utils\Mails
    arguments: ['@templating']
    public: true
```

**My Mail.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Site\PagesBundle\Utils;

use Site\PagesBundle\Entity\User;
use Site\PagesBundle\Entity\UserCas;

class Mails
{
    private $templating;

    public function __construct(EngineInterface $templating)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }

    public function sendMail($user,$raisonMail)
    {
        $transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance();
        $mailer = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);

        // Entête
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setFrom(array('############' => '############'))
            //->setTo($user->getEmail());
            ->setTo("############")
            ->setCharset('utf-8')
            ->setContentType('text/html');

        switch($raisonMail)
        {
            case 'formulaireInscription':
                dump($user);
                // (1) Confirmation de demande d'inscription
                $message->setSubject("subject")
                        ->setBody($this->templating->render("@Pages/swiftmail/CreationCompte/DemandeCreationCompte.html.twig",array(
                            'prenom'=>$user->getPrenom(),
                            'nom'=>$user->getNom(),
                            )));
                break;

//... other cases
```

**In my controller :**

```
 $templating = new EngineInterface;
    $mail = new Mail($templating);
    $mail->get('email_management')->sendEmail($user,$motif);
```

But now I've this error :

> You must set a loader first.

[image]

Can someone help me please ? Thanks !

Comment: The implementation looks a bit confusing in regards whether the intention is to have this working as a service (which is probably the recommended option) or as an utility class. If you are trying to go for the service option, the namespace & control usage is wrong (initialization etc) and also the service definition itself might be problematic as you're defining the service name to be the same as the existing templating. If you're trying to go for an utility class, then you should drop the services file definition completely (I'm not sure if the twig_environment creation will work like that).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm starting in Symfony, I'm missing some notions. Could you be a little clearer with an example please?

Comment: sure, I added a rough example how this could be done using a service class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the intention is to go for the service based option. Please note in general that the service class is intended to be moved into different folder in the project (to be under PagesBundle/Service folder).

services.yml (please note the changed path)

```
email_management:
    class: Site\PagesBundle\Service\EmailManagementService
    arguments: ['@templating']
    public: true
```

EmailManagementService.php (please note the changed location & namespace)

```
<?php

namespace Site\PagesBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;
use Site\PagesBundle\Entity\User;
use Site\PagesBundle\Entity\UserCas;

class Mails
{
    private $templating;

    public function __construct(EngineInterface $templating)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }

    ...
}
```

Usage in controller:

```
$this->get('email_management')->sendMail($user,'formulaireInscription');
```

Comment: Ah yes I see, the path used will allow me to better find myself there. I'll change that once it works. So I made the necessary changes, replacing 'email_service' in the controller with 'email_management' so the name of the service. And I get the error:
The "email_management" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.

Comment: ah, true. Forgot to add the public to the service definition as I generally have all services public instead of defining that explicitly per service. I updated the answer above to fix that.

Comment: Okay thanks ! So, in my controller, if I want to use the "Mails" class, I've to do that :

$templating = new EngineInterface;
        $mail = new Mail($templating);
        $mail->get('email_management')->sendEmail($user,$motif);

?

Comment: nope, just the single row from my answer - the two first lines are not needed (nor are they correct).

Comment: Okay, I will make the updates (namespace) to see that. For the moment, using the single line, I've this error : Attempted to call an undefined method named "sendEmail" of class "Site\PagesBundle\Utils\Mails".
Did you mean to call "sendMail"?

Comment: Seems like I wrote that in wrong format in my answer. But basically you just need to fix the call to match your function name for that. Updated that on the answer (to call the existing "sendMail" function of the service).

Comment: So, if I understand, I've in my 'PagesBundle' : Site => PagesBundle => Service => EmailManagement.php, is it true ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193132/discussion-between-ejuhjav-and-eronn).